# Calling ruby script from groovy

Tags: ruby, groovy

I have a groovy script and I need to call a ruby script.

I would like to pass arguments to Ruby script and would like to capture the output from Ruby script to use it in Groovy Script. Can somebody suggest how I can do this? I tried `Process.execute()`. It works for other dos commands but not for `cmd /c ruby test.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

Since a ruby file isn't a batch file you don't need to use cmd to execute it. You could do

```
Process.execute("ruby.exe test.rb")
```

Assuming ruby.exe is on your path. Another option depending on your requirements may be to use [JRuby](http://www.jruby.org) which will allow you to run ruby code on the JVm and integrate nicely with Groovy.