# groovy execute fails while the same works from command line

Tags: groovy, cmd, execute

I have a statement to execute:

`cmd /c "C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\jekyll.bat" build -s C:\IdeaWorkspace\Distribution\Web\public_site_templates -d C:\IdeaWorkspace\Distribution\Web\public`

If I execute this from the command line it works. If I execute it in a groovy script it fails.

```
    println jekyllCommand // prints the code above
    Process p = jekyllCommand.execute();
```

It gives me :

```
'"ruby.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I added C:\Ruby200-x64\bin to Path variable; and the code works when I execute it from the command line. Groovy keeps giving the not-recognizing-ruby.exe error.

Comment: Take a look here, even if I think you might have already done that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714763/calling-ruby-script-from-groovy

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that after changing the environment variables, the IDE should be restarted. Restarting it solved my problem.